What motivated Democritus to discover the volume of a cone?
In the works of Archimedes, we are told that Democritus was the first to discover that the volume of a cone is 1/3 that of the cylinder with the same base and same height. I am curious to know about what motivated Democritus to discover this. Other than intellectual curiosity, which is a somewhat unsatifying answer, was there some operational motivation, i.e. in Greek astronomy or mechanics? I can't think of why someone in Greek times was trying to find the volume of a cone, other than as an intermediate step to calculate the volume of a sphere maybe as Archimedes did, or for some mechanical/architectural reason which the Greeks had that I am unaware of. Any known theories or sources?

We do not know and we will never know. Democritus's works did not survive, we know about him stating the volume of a cone from Archimedes, who lived two centuries later and does not elaborate. Cones are similar to pyramids, and Democritus was reportedly in contact with Egyptians, and they came up in connection with gnomons and sundials. Rinner speculates that this prompted Greek geometers to study properties of cones and their sections.
